# Shortcode Not Implementing In TopBar Menu

Tags: shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I have a shortcode for currency switcher in wordpress which im trying to get it implemented to the top bar menu and when i try to do it it just simply displays the shorcode rather than having the dropdown list for multi currencies [woocommerce_currency_switcher_drop_down_box] Heres the shortcode and https://snipboard.io/3SjMre.jpg here's the ss for wwhat how the problem occurs for the website https://executiverugs.com/ . I got no support from theme as it got expired and this shortcode isnt implementing in the topbar menu. Help Please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try editing the `header.php` file.

add following code to the file below the opening `<body>` tag at the place where your shortcode now is

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_currency_switcher_drop_down_box]'); ?>
```

will do the trick

Comment: Hey Heres the file link can you please guide i cant do it https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xq5N8_Z6kkIogO045ixEBhT_YcuGnXgF/view?usp=sharing thanks

Comment: According to the documentation there is no such thing as, if you can't make any edits to this I think you need to change `[woocommerce_currency_switcher_drop_down_box]` replace that from your example in your menu with following `[wcc_switcher]`

Comment: nah dude it still wont work im sad man its 12 hours now

Comment: Are you still sure if that shortcode exist? try put following code in your theme `functions.php

 if( !function_exists('woocommerce_currency_switcher_drop_down_box ') ){ function woocommerce_currency_switcher_drop_down_box(){ return 'mydropdown'; } }

add_shortcode('woocommerce_currency_switcher_drop_down_box','woocommerce_currency_switcher_drop_down_box');`

Comment: Hey DUde check the website again i addedd thiss <?php } ?>
       <div> <?php echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_currency_switcher_drop_down_box]'); ?> </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>   Now it is there but the thing is i cant take it to left to order tracking help pleaseeeee i did this in header-6.php

Comment: Hey dude.. it's already there

Comment: dude <?php echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_currency_switcher_drop_down_box]'); ?> this helped me then i had to create div and then find the find to change the name and then create custom css codes so it would look better it took a alot of timeeee but it couldnt had been done with your code thankssss